# Label text after text in table caption

Tags: tables, captions

I need to move label text to the end of table caption, but there is newline at the end of text...

```
\documentclass[pdf, unicode, 12pt, a4paper, oneside, fleqn]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2B]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}


\DeclareCaptionFormat{reverse}{#3#2#1}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{fullparens}{\bothIfFirst{#1}{ }#2}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{fill}{\hfill}
\captionsetup[longtable]{format=reverse,labelformat=fullparens,
              labelsep=fill}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{4.5cm}|p{11cm}|}
    \caption[Caption text]{Caption text} \label{table_1} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    Title 1 & Title 2 \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Продолжение на следующей странице}}
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    1 & 2 \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

And here is result:
[image]
Hot to remove new line? The result should be like this : "Text. Таблица 2".

Comment: Please extend your code snipped to complete small document, which we can copy and compile on our computers.

Comment: Zarko, i extended my code.

Comment: There are only two ways to put everything in one line:  Put it all inside the \caption, or use \caption{} and put it all outside the caption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following caption formatting:

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{reverse}{#3#2#1}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{fullparens}{(\bothIfFirst{#1}{ }#2)\hfill}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{fill}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}\hfil\qquad }
\captionsetup{format=reverse,
              labelformat=fullparens,
              labelsep=fill, labelfont=bf}
```

[image]

or

[image]

Complete MWE producing the second caption is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}


\DeclareCaptionFormat{reverse}{#3#2#1}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{fullparens}{(\bothIfFirst{#1}{ }#2)\hfill}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{fill}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}\hfil\qquad }
\captionsetup{format=reverse,
              labelformat=fullparens,
              labelsep=fill, labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{4.5cm}|p{11cm}|}
    \caption[Caption text]{Very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, long caption text.} \label{table_1} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    Title 1 & Title 2 \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx}}
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    1 & 2 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

If you like to have table label aligned with right border of table, than change definition for label separator to

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{fill}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}\hfill}
```

in you will obtain:

[image]

Comment: You can also use \captionsetup[longtable]...  But I still see two lines.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I believe that caption setup is independent from `longtable`. I suggest dirty hack, since I don't know, how to remove `par` which is somewhere hidden in caption definition on the end of caption main text.

Comment: @Zarko - One can setup figure, table and any other declared \@captype to use different formats.  Then again, you don't have to.